# Angular POST to API doesn't pass data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, api, post

So I am using [makoframework](https://makoframework.com) and AngularJS for my project and currently having some problems.

So in my table `customers`, the `customer_name` field is not nullable. My current code where I get all the data from `customers` table is this.

```
function CustomerCtrl($scope, Customers, DTOptionsBuilder) {
   $scope.loadCustomers = function () {
        Customers.getCustomers()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.customers = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}

//factory

function Customers($http) {
  return {
        getCustomers: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/customers');
  },
        addCustomer: function (data) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/customers',
                    data: data
                });
            }
}
```

The `/api/customers` returns a json response and it works well with my angular code.

Now I have another route in my php which is `/api/products POST` and when I try adding data using `Advanced Rest Client` of Chrome.. it also works.

But then when using with my angular code, it doesnt work already.

**My code**

```
    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
           alert($scope.customerData.full_name); // THIS ALERT IS WORKING
            var data = {
                'name': $scope.customerData.full_name,
            }
            Customers.addCustomer(data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.customerSpinner = true;
                    var message = response.data.message;
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.customerData = {};
                    $scope.loadCustomers();
                    Materialize.toast('<i class="mdi-navigation-check left"></i> ' + message, 3000, 'green darken-2 white-text');
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    }
```

**// HTML**

```
   <div id="addCustomerModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Add Customer</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <form action="" class="col s12">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="full_name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="customerData.full_name">
                        <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="waves-effect btn-flat teal lighten-2 white-text" ng-click="addCustomer()">Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**// `/api/products`**

```
$routes->post('/api/customers', 'app\controllers\CustomerController::create');
    public function create()
    {
        // take note that this works using a restful client from chrome
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->customer_name = $this->request->post('name');

        if($customer->save()) {
            $result = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Customer '.$this->request->post('name').' has been added.');
        }
        else {
            $result = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error adding customer.');
        }
        return $this->jsonResponse($result);
    }
```

As you can see in the `addCustomer $scope`, I added an `alert($scope.customerData.full_name);` and it actually works. I get the data.

But I get an SQL error saying

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_name' cannot be null"
```

Which means the data is not passed to the API though it works when I am using a REST Client from Chrome.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

First, I json stringified the data variable:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  'name': $scope.customerData.full_name,
});
```

and changed content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
           addCustomer: function (data) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/customers',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                });
            }
```

And in my php controller I tried:

```
return $this->jsonResponse($this->request->post());
```

And I get this:

[image]

Now I just have to access it. When I try `$this->request->post('name')`, I still get an error. So How can I properly get the json object?

Comment: you need to show your PHP code for `/api/products POST`

Comment: if you add `console.log(data)` before `Customers.addCustomer(data)` what do you get?

Comment: @CodeGodie I get this http://i.imgur.com/BnTJ2EW.png (dont mind the other undefined)

Comment: in php, in the first line of our `create()` method, return the parameter `return $this->request->post('name')` , then console.log on JS to see what gets returned.. Ideally it would be best to use the Network tab on you web inspector and check the http response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131395/discussion-between-fewflyby-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 0):

$http POST by default send data in json, so you need to parse json string in PHP before you can access the name property or you can change the headers in $http params to application/x-www-form-urlencoded if you want to get the params like when you submit a form.